# Bulk re-activating users in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ftp

Is there any way to bulk re-subscribe users in Marketing Cloud?

I currently have lots of users who are held, undeliverable or bounced in their _listsubscribers status but whose email addresses have subsequently been changed on Sales Cloud vs. Marketing Cloud.

From this article it seems I need to update to unsubscribed then to active:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000322262&type=1&mode=1

But I obviously don't want to do this manually so have a data export and import set up with a query that identifies everyone who:

[1] has a _ListSubscribers status of 'held' or 'bounced'
[2] has a different email address in Sales Cloud vs. Marketing Cloud based on our synchronised data extension (linked to the more accurate/up to date Sales Cloud database)
[3] has not opted out of email on Sales Cloud

Everything seems to work as expected except the _ListSubsribers statuses for the relevant contacts aren't actually updated following the automated .csv import.

The automation currently goes:

SQL query - verification target data extension isn't empty - data extract - file transfer to FTP - data import from FTP to Marketing Cloud.

Does anyone know if there are limitations I'm not aware of that are stopping this from working or if there is a better way of achieving this?

I have tried updating the subscriber status to both 'unsubscribed' and 'held' using the import.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 1):

You can use SSJS to bulk update your subscriber status. First you need to initiate your All subscribers list, and use *Subscribers.Update* on each record. The below example is done with hardcoded values, but you can easily expand it to iterate through all rows in a data extension and do this in bulk:

```
var myList = List.Init("All Subscribers - 778012");
var status = myList.Subscribers.Update({EmailAddress:"john.doe@example.com", SubscriberKey:"12345"},"Active");
```

Keep in mind, that this process needs to run in your ENT BU

Comment: Thanks Lukas - I haven't used SSJS before but will look into doing this with either SSJS or AMPScript.